# AWS S3 SSE GetObject requires secret key

Tags: amazon-s3

The idea was to generate a random key for every file being uploaded, pass this key to S3 in order to encrypt it and store the key in the database. Once the user wants to access the file, the key is read from the database and passed to S3 once again.

The first part works. My objects are uploaded and encrypted successfully, but I have issues with retrieving them.

***Retrieving files with request headers set:***

When setting the request headers such as `x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm` etc. when performing the GET request to the resource, works, and I am able to access it. But since I want to these resources as `src` to an `<img>-Tag`, I cannot perform GET requests which require headers to be set.

Thus, I thought about:

***Pre signing urls:***

To create a pre signed url, I built the HMAC SHA1 of the required string and used it as a signature. The calculated signature is accepted by S3 but I get the following error when requesting the pre signed URL:

> Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with Customer provided keys must provide an appropriate secret key.

The URL has the form:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-id/resource-id?x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm=AES256&AWSAccessKeyId=MyAccessKey&Expires=1429939889&Signature=GeneratedSignature
```

The reason why the error is shown seems to be pretty clear to me. At no point in the signing process was the encryption key used. Thus, the request cannot work. As a result, I added the encryption key as Base64, and Md5 representation as parameters to the URL. The URL now has the following format:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-id/resource-id?x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm=AES256&AWSAccessKeyId=MyAccessKey&Expires=1429939889&Signature=GeneratedSignature&x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key=Base64_Key&x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5=Md5_Key
```

Although the key is now present (imho), I do get the same error message.

***Question***
Does anyone know, how I can access my encrypted files with a `GET` request which does not provide any headers such as `x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems intuitive enough to me that what you are trying should have worked.

Apparently, though, when they say "headers"...

> you must provide all the encryption headers in your client application.
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html#sse-c-how-to-programmatically-intro</sup>

... they do indeed actually mean **headers** and S3 doesn't accept these particular values when delivered as part of the query string, as you would expect, since S3 sometimes is somewhat flexible in that regard.

I've tested this, and that's the conclusion I've come to: doing this isn't supported.

A `GET` request with `x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm=AES256` included in the query string (and signature), along with the `X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption-Customer-Key` and `X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption-Customer-Key-MD5` *headers* does work as expected... as I believe you've discovered... but putting the key and key-md5 in the query string, with or without including it in the signature seems like a dead end.

It seemed somewhat strange, at first, that they wouldn't allow this in the query string, since so many other things are allowed there... but then again, if you're going to the trouble of encrypting something, there seems little point in revealing the encryption key in a link... not to mention that the key would then be captured in the S3 access logs, leaving the encryption seeming fairly well pointless all around -- and perhaps that was their motivation for requiring it to actually be sent in the headers and not the query string.

Based on what I've found in testing, though, I don't see a way to use encrypted objects with customer-provided keys in hyperlinks, directly.

Indirectly, of course, a reverse proxy in front of the S3 bucket could do the translation for you, taking the appropriate values from the query string and placing them into the headers, instead... but it's really not clear to me what's to be gained by using customer-provided encryption keys for downloadable objects, compared to letting S3 handle the at-rest encryption with AWS-managed keys.  At-rest encryption is all you're getting either way.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. However, my problem isn't really solved. I want to use consumer encryption to make sure that only the owner of the files is allowed to view them. Thus, having a link containing the key isn't a real problem since my backend makes sure only to send the link to the correct user. When using Amazon's key mechanisms I don't know how to control who can view files and who doesn't. At this time it seems to me that when using Amazon's key, I have to create a user at Amazon for every user of mine and than update the objects acl accordingly.

Comment: *"my backend makes sure only to send the link to the correct user"* ... if true, it sounds as if you are overlooking the obvious: if the user isn't authorized to see a file, don't give them a signed URL for it.   Objects in S3 aren't publicly readable unless you make them that way, either through object ACLs or through bucket policy.  An unsigned link to a properly configured object and bucket doesn't even reveal whether such an object even exists.  It's just `403 Forbidden`.  Let me know if I can clarify that.